# Trying customize Fedora rescue image - how do I go about this?

Tags: fedora, live-usb, livecd, iso

Most of what I've found on this involves changing install discs - which I don't really need. I just want to install a handful of extra packages and maybe some helpful scripts onto the Fedora rescue image and burn it to a disc for me and my boss to use when we image or tinker with computers (our imaging process is over NFS).

Is there a good straightforward process to this or am I looking at rolling my own whole setup?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

There is extensive [documentation](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FedoraLiveCD#Download_and_Create_Live_image_or_Live_USB) on building Fedora live CDs. The rescue functionality is built-in to them, IIRC.